# Allocation of 3 subsets of unique items into 2 holders of fixed size

Tags: combinatorics

This is a really basic combinatorial problem, and I was sure I solved it correctly, but apparently I made a mistake somewhere.

There's a set of 12 items $\mathcal{A}$ divided into three subsets: $\mathcal{A}_1 = \{A, B,C \} , \mathcal{A}_2 = \{\alpha ,\beta, \gamma, \delta \}, \mathcal{A}_3 = \{1,2,3,4,5 \}$ and two distinct 'egg holders' (e.g. Blue and Red) each size 6. What's the total number of allocations, such that $\mathcal{A}_1$ is allocated in Blue egg-holder only, $\mathcal{A}_2$ in Red only and $\mathcal{A}_3$ are 'dont' care' - can be anywhere and the $order \ matters$, i.e. (A,B,C,1,2,3) and (A,B,1,2,3,C) are two distinct allocations (hence 'egg-holder')

Clearly there are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to fit $\mathcal{A}_1$ into Blue, but since the order matters we multiply by $3!$. Now we select 3 out of 5 'don't care' guys, and their order also matters, os we multiuply by $3!$.

Now for $\mathcal{A}_2$ and Red egg-holder. The calculation is pretty much the same, but for the don't care guys we have $\binom{2}{2} \cdot 2!$

So the full solution will be 
$$
\binom{6}{3} 3! \binom{5}{3} 3! \binom{6}{4} 4! \binom{2}{2} 2! = \frac{6!5!6!}{3!2!}
$$

Apparetnly this is wrong. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is correct.  Another way to get the result is to say that there are $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to choose which 3 elements of $A_3$ go into the blue egg-holder, and then there are $6!$ arrangements of the elements within each egg-holder.  Thus the total number of arrangements is $\binom{5}{3}(6!)^2 = \frac{5!6!6!}{3!2!}$, as you concluded.